# Debugging wireshark dissector

Tags: wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I am writing my first wireshark dissector. I am writing it in Lua, using [this as an example](https://mika-s.github.io/wireshark/lua/dissector/2017/11/04/creating-a-wireshark-dissector-in-lua-1.html). On the [second page](https://mika-s.github.io/wireshark/lua/dissector/2017/11/06/creating-a-wireshark-dissector-in-lua-2.html) it says that I can use functions like critical(), warn(), debug() to help debug the code. However, when I add even the simplest

```
critical("foo")
```

wireshark complains that

```
attempt to call global 'critical' (a nil value)
```

I can't seem to figure out how to use these utility functions. What am I missing?

**UPDATE:** In case it is relevant, I am running Wireshark 3.0.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made that tutorial.

It looks like the logging functions were removed from Wireshark in 3.0 ([release notes](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/relnotes/wireshark-3.0.0.html)):

> Lua: the various logging functions (debug, info, message, warn and critical) have been removed. Use the print function instead for
>   debugging purposes.

So use `print()` instead:

```lua
print("foo")
```

Comment: Thank you (both for the clarification and providing that tutorial)